# Java : Define abstract method with infinite numbers of param of any type

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, casting, abstract

I'm currently trying to define an abstract method which allow an infinite number of parameters, of any type.

**What?**

I want to write something like this in the abstract class `<AType> exec(Any[] args)`

The concrete class can override it by doing this `List<AType> exec(AType1 arg1, AType2 arg2)`

or by doing this `List<AType> exec(AType1 arg1, AType2 arg2, AnotherType1 arg3)`

**But ... WHY?**

Actually I'm trying to do some *dependency injection*. The concrete class overrides a method nammed `getParams():String[]` which returns an array of symbolic names.

At runtime, a class retrieves the *symbolic names* (which map on instances), and call `exec` method with proper concrete parameters.

**What I have found**

I can't do this with `exec(Object... o)`. (By the way I'm not sure to understand why the Java compiler refuses this option since every Object map with this signature. By reading the answers of this article : [Overriding abstract generic method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427798/overriding-abstract-generic-method-in-java), I didn't understand why it is not allowed).

I can't do this by following [this oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) since the generic type `T` must be unique.

Is it even possible ?
If so, what can I do ?

Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: Inheritance is simply the wrong tool here, as far as Java is concerned. You can use proxies, bytecode manipulation and/or reflection to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer @biziclop ! Since this abstract method is a contract for a user, I'm trying to force him to define a method called exec in th sublass without forcing anything on the parameters. As far as I know, Proxies, bytecode and reflection manipulation target runtime not compile time. Am I right ?

Comment: What kind of exception do you get when you try something like `List<?> exec(Object... o) {...}`? I tried something locally with JDK 1.8 and didn't get any errors.

Comment: By doing what I described in the post I'm getting : "AConcreteClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method exec(java.lang.Object...) in AnAbstractClass". The concrete class exec method looks like this `exec(RandomClass randomClass)`

Comment: @BenjaminBenni Don't force them to have the method a certain name, relying on name magic is a fragile idea. Give them an annotation instead that they can attach to any method they like. (e.g. like JUnit's `@Test` annotation)

Comment: @biziclop thanks that's a good option !

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937003/abstract-method-with-variable-list-of-arguments